# Can I do a command-line install with the 12.10 media?

Tags: installation, command-line, 12.10

From what I read on the mailing list, and on here, it looks like there won't be any alternative install CDs for Quantal Quetzal. I used to love those, as they enabled me to quickly whip out a command-line only install.

With a base install, I could load xorg, my desired Window Manager (usually openbox or razor-qt), and keep my Ubuntu installation tiny and cruft free.

Is that no more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the Alternate CD has been dropped, you can still do it using the [Minimal ISO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD).
Everything is downloaded fresh from the repositories, so not need to update post-install.

PS: In case you were wondering, here is what the installer [looks like](http://maketecheasier.com/install-a-minimal-ubuntu-on-old-laptop/2012/02/24).

Comment: Oh man, I love you. In a totally not-weird type of way.

Answer (score 1):

You can always switch to a text based installation where you also can add special boot parameters by pressing and holding down any key while booting from a live CD.

This will open a Grub text based menu similar to this:

[image]

For more information on boot options see

- [Community Help Wiki: Boot Options](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions)

Comment: I had to press a key to add 'noefi' for Acer. But I was wondering, what's the boot option to have a command-line only install?